# Android Studio Libraries and aar

Tags: java, android, maven, gradle

I'm currently building an Android library. The library is divided into two parts:

1. Core features and functionality
2. Utility classes such as extended Activities, FragmentActivities etc.

Now when I tried building the library's structure as such, including ActionBarSherlock and AppCompat V7 created a conflict for Gradle. The two libraries are mutually exclusive. My solution was to build a core library and 2 wrapper libraries (one for ABS and another for AppCompat V7) then provide the user with both options. So I did the following:

1. For the core library project "core" I ran the gradlew assemble command. This in turn generated an aar file for my library "core.aar".
2. I created another library project "support" and added the core.aar as a dependency in my local maven for that project. (More info on that [here](http://codebutler.com/2013/07/02/android-libraries-with-gradle-and-android-studio))
3. I ran ./gradlew assemble for the support library which in turn created support.aar.
4. I finally added the support.aar file as a dependency for my application (just like step 2)

When I finish all that, I get a compilation error for my app saying that certain resources cannot be found in my library files in the exploded-aar folder. To be more precise, in my library I have certain drawables that are used in certain layout files, both in the library. These are not found anywhere.

Any idea what could be causing the problem?